# Equality of two Dedekind cuts

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, real-numbers

Suppose we have a Dedekind cut $A$ defined as $\left\{ x\in \mathbb{Q}\left| {{x}^{2}}>2\And x>0 \right. \right\}$. For good measure let's add another Dedekind cut $B$ defined as $\left\{ x\in \mathbb{Q}\left| x>r \right. \right\}$. I'm struggling a bit to prove that if $A=B$ then ${{r}^{2}}=2$. Of course, if $A=B$ then ${{x}^{2}}>2\And x>0\Leftrightarrow x>r$.

Comment: I don't know if I want to write a whole post on an answer so here is an idea. Suppose positive rational $r$ is such that $r^2$ is greater then $2$. The rationals can be an arbitrary distance to each other, so one might expect a positive rational $q$ so that that $q^2>2$ but $q<r$. Look at the conditions needed to be in $A$ and $B$. In which sets of $A$ and $B$ is $q$ in? What can happen if r is such that $r^2<2$? What must we now conclude if this can't be the case?

Comment: Basically, we prove than both ${{r}^{2}}>2$ and ${{r}^{2}}<2$ lead to contradiction?

Comment: Yeah. This is a very common method because it allows us to exploit the 'denseness' of the rationals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $r^2<2$. Note that $r<2$, because otherwise $r^2\geq4$. Choose $q\in\mathbb Q$ with $r^2<q<2$. We have, for $0<\delta<1$, 
$$
(r+\delta)^2=r^2+2r\delta+\delta^2<q+\delta(2r+\delta)<q+\delta(4+\delta)<q+5\delta.
$$
If we choose $\delta<\frac{2-q}5$, we get that $(r+\delta)^2<2$. Then $r+\delta\in B\setminus A$, a contradiction.

Similarly, suppose that $r^2>2$. Then $r>1$; if $0<\delta<\frac{r^2-2}{2r}$ and also $\delta<2r$, then
$$
(r-\delta)^2=r^2-2r\delta+\delta^2>r^2-2r\delta>2.
$$
So $r-\delta\in A\setminus B$, a contradiction.

The only possibility left is that $r^2=2$.